# React Native WebView iFrame Reference Local Files

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am working on a project at work to build a React Native app for our [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system). The feature I am working on is the ability to download content when connected to the internet, and then be able to run that downloaded content when not connected to the internet.

The content that will be downloaded is websites running [SCORM](https://scorm.com/), so I **cannot** reference the downloaded HTML file directly from a `<WebView />` because there has to be a parent view that contains a JavaScript SCORM API. Instead I have the following HTML file locally that I reference in a `<WebView />`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="./lib/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/PortalAPI.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/GlobalAPI.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/Scorm2004DataModel.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/Scorm2004API.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/ScormAPI.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/SimpleAJAX.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/Common.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/Common_nw.js"></script>
        <style>
            #lmscontentFrame {
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: red;">
        <iframe
            application="yes"
            frameborder="0"
            id="lmscontentFrame"
            name="lmscontentFrame"
            noresize=""
            scrolling="auto"
            src=""
        ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above HTML file is referenced as follows:

```
const scormTrackHtml = require('../files/scormTrack/index.html');
const webView = (
    ...
    <WebView
        source={scormTrackHtml}
        ...
    />
    ...
);
```

I then use the `injectedJavaScript` property of `WebView` to inject JavaScript that changes the `src` of the `<iframe />` to point at the downloaded content (e.g. `file:///data/user/0/com.app/files/activity-4260/index.html`). But nothing happens. If I change the injected JavaScript to point the `src` at a HTTP website URL it works fine. I have also tried removing the `file://` prefix, but that just results in a `Cannot GET /data/user/0/...` message.

Now, if I add a `test.html` file in the same directory as the above defined static `scormTrackHtml` wrapper HTML file and update the injected JavaScript to set the `src` to `./test.html` then it loads. So the `<iframe />` is able to load local files, but I can't determine if it just doesn't allow you to use the `file://` protocol, or if it just doesn't have permission to access the `/data/user/0/com.app/files` directory and if not where I should put it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue came down to file permissions (i.e. the static HTML file bundled with my app wasn't allowed to reference a file in the documents folder).

A partial solution was to write the static HTML file I was bundling with my app to the documents directory so it was in the same place as the downloaded content it was trying to access. This allowed the `<iframe />` to load the downloaded content, but was only a partial solution because the content in the `<iframe />` needs to access the SCORM API JavaScript object located in the parent window, but Chrome blocks an `<iframe />` using the `file://` protocol from accessing variable in `window.parent` because of cross-origin security issues.

Sadly, the final solution appears to be starting a static file HTTP server in the document directory so I can load the content through the `http://` protocol to get around the security issues.